# How to easily de-serialize polymorphic types from XML to POCOs (using XML Schema)?

Tags: c#, xsd, polymorphism, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

Suppose I want to parse any of these XML elements:

```
<Server                      hostName="foobar"                      />
<WebServer                   hostName="foobar"                      />
<WebServer                   hostName="foobar" listeningOnPort="80" />
<Server xsi:type="WebServer" hostName="foobar" listeningOnPort="80" />
```

which adhere to the following XML Schema declarations:

```
<xsd:element name="Server" type="IServer" />
<xsd:element name="WebServer" substitutionGroup="Server" type="IWebServer" />

<xsd:complexType name="IServer">
  <xsd:attribute name="hostName" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="IWebServer">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="IServer">
      <xsd:attribute name="listeningOnPort" type="xsd:int" use="optional" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

to corresponding CLR objects of these types:

```
class Server : IServer { .. }               // [CorrespondsTo("Server")]
class WebServer : Server, IWebServer { .. } // [CorrespondsTo("WebServer")]

interface IServer                           // [CorrespondsTo("IServer")]
{
    string HostName { get; set; }           // [CorrespondsTo("hostName")]
}

interface IWebServer : IServer              // [CorrespondsTo("IWebServer")]
{
    int? ListeningOnPort { get; set; }      // [CorrespondsTo("listeningOnPort")]
}
```

Is there anything in the .NET framework or any mature, lightweight XML parsing library that will achieve this without me having to write lots of code? Does having an XML Schema actually help with the XML-to-CLR type mapping?

- A declarative solution for XML-to-CLR type mappings would be nice, e.g. via C# attributes.
- Optional attributes should be transformed correctly to nullable types.
- `<Server xsi:type="WebServer" ... />` should result in a `WebServer` object.

Comment: I suggest you create a simple class hierarchy, then serialize it using the XML Serializer; adjust to make some of the elements be attributes and serialize again; then check to see if it might not be good enough, despite not matching your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET supports XML to CLR serialization natively.

There is a command line tool called "XSD.exe" which takes a series of .xsd documents and creates the corresponding C# objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx

Then in code, you use the XmlSerializer class to serialize and deserialize.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. I'm a bit disappointed that the .NET-native deserialization doesn't support nullable types, nor interfaces. If I don't find a way to get these to work, I'll do it this way and transform the de-serialized objects into my own object model (API)... that should be easy enough.

Comment: I accepted this answer not because it fully answers my question, but because I've seen that .NET doesn't natively provide what I seek -- nevertheless this is good enough to get my code working.